# method: color console string with parameter object[] prms

Tags: c#, colors, console

I cannot create a function myself that takes the a text with `params object[]` and colourizes it.

```
protected void ColorToConsole(ConsoleColor c, string s, params object[] p) {
    Console.ForegroundColor = c;
    Console.Write(string.Format(s, p));
}
```

I would like to call the function like this: `ColorToConsole(ConsoleColor.Blue, "I like {0}", p`. I expect only the `p` to be colored in blue. I'm trying to get another method where I can provide multiple Colors for the different `p` but i'm stuck here.

Comment: I have updated my answer and finally it matches to the function that you were trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 4

Here is code that you wants, it's parsing given value,finding places where to put colorized text and doing it.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello {{1}} {0}", "Henry");
            WriteLine(ConsoleColor.Red, "Hello {0},{2} {1} asd {1} {0} {2}", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
            WriteLine(ConsoleColor.Red, "Hello {{1}} {0}", "Henry");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {{1}} {0}", "Henry","David");
            WriteLine(ConsoleColor.Green,"Hello {{1}} {0}", "Henry", "David");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello {{1}} {1} {0}", "Henry");
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                WriteLine(ConsoleColor.Red, "Hello {{1}} {1} {0}", "Henry");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }

        }
        public static void WriteLine(ConsoleColor c, string value, params object[] prms)
        {
            var regEx = new Regex("{[0-9]+}");
            var matches = regEx.Matches(value);
            int i = 0;
            int newLenght = (value.Length - 3 * (prms.Length) + (int)prms.Sum(x => ((string)x).Length));
            var valueArr = value.ToCharArray();
            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                while (i < m.Index && i < valueArr.Length)
                {
                    Console.Write(valueArr[i]);
                    i++;
                }

                if (valueArr[i].Equals('{') && i+m.Value.Length< valueArr.Length && valueArr[i + m.Value.Length].Equals('}'))
                {
                    i += m.Value.Length;
                    Console.Write(m.Value.Trim('{', '}'));
                }
                else if (int.Parse(m.Value.Trim('{', '}')) < prms.Length)
                {
                    i += m.Value.Length;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = c;
                    Console.Write(prms[int.Parse(m.Value.Trim('{', '}'))]);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Index must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.");
                }
            }
            while (i < valueArr.Length)
            {
                Console.Write(valueArr[i]);
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output will be the following:
[image]

Comment: This is going to fail with a string of the form `"Hello, {{1}} {0}"`. The expected output of that, if the first parameter is "Joe" is: `Hello, {1} Joe`. Your code doesn't handle the `{` and `}` literals. In addition, it doesn't handle format strings. For example if the string were "Hello {0:P2}". Finally, your use of the regular expression `"{[0-9]*}"` means that it will fail if the string `"{}"` exists. Your code also will fail if there are more than 10 strings (i.e. `{10}`), because you're only parsing the first digit. In short, this implementation is full of holes.

Comment: I have updated answer for cases "{{1}}","{}" and "{10}". In the question there was nothing about using formatting string. And I have not said that my code handles it.

Comment: I don't think your fix actually fixes the problem of "{{1}}". It looks like you'll still try to replace the "{1}" with an argument, which is not the intended behavior. Have you actually tested your code? And, no, the OP didn't say anything about a formatting string, but that's something that it would be reasonable to expect in "writeline with color" method.

Comment: @JimMischel I think now it handles "{{1}}" case. As for the formatting, I think that in this question there is no need to implement it. I also agree with you that it was worth noting that formatting is one of the main features of this function and needs to be implemented in future.

Comment: Not quite. It fails for `WriteLine("Hello {{{1}}} George, {0}", "Henry", "David");` In that case it's supposed to output `{David}`, but instead it outputs `{{1}}`. You might get the idea here that regular expressions aren't going to be the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: @JimMischel Do I understand correctly that in Console.WriteLine  "{{" and "}}" is meaning that don't look at params and just print "{" or "}"?

Comment: That's correct. See the "Escaping Braces" topic in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I do not think, `string.Format` has that capability what you are expecting.

But you can customize the function by using sub strings.

I tried the below function, And it is doing good. 
I see the output similar to your expectation. Look into comments in below code. A sample just for string input. For object array scroll down a bit for second piece of code.

```
        public void ColorToConsole(ConsoleColor c, string s, string p)
        {
           //GET THE SUBSTRING TILL {0} AND WRITE IT TO CONSOLE
            string substr = s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf("{0}"));
            Console.Write(substr);

            //NOW SET THE FORE GROUND COLOR. WRITE THE REST
            Console.ForegroundColor = c;
            Console.Write(p);
        }
```

If you want each of your `p` elements in different colors, you can try the below code.

```
 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
 Console.Write(p[0]);

 //RESET THE COLOR.
 Console.ResetColor();

 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
 Console.Write(p[1]);
```